How to remove rusty residue left on rear wheel from metal on metal, severely neglected brakes?
Relative brought me her car with severely neglected brakes, metal on metal, so bad that the caliper piston itself started wearing into the rotor.
Needless to say, new rotors, pads, and calipers were installed. Bled the system.
However, all that grinding metal "sprayed" a thick residue of metal dust onto the custom wheel.
How to best clean it off the wheel?

Have you already tried and failed using ordinary soap and water? If you would state your specific issues or concerns, you'll have a better chance of receiving useful feedback.

Well done fixing your relative's car before it ended up in an accident! That must make you feel pleased. I second @MTA, it would be useful to know what you have tried so far, or if you have specific concerns.
